# Embedded Power App in a Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, powerapps

My company has a power app and Xamarin Forms app. They want to merge them in a single app. I was not able to find any information about if is it even possible ? I found out that it is possible to create a web page which has build-in power app . How will it behave if i will put power app inside Xamarin Forms WebView?

Comment: I know nothing about Power Apps, but I have a lot of experience porting and maintaining/extending legacy software of different kinds. Even knowing nothing about the specifics, I can tell you this is almost certainly a disastrous idea, with little hope of ending up with a useful app. At best, it will be clumsy and disliked by users. At worst, it will not work at all. Its almost certainly better to pick one platform, and treat the "other app" as a "prototype": rewrite its functionality from scratch, within the chosen platform. Salvaging whatever logic or UI layout you can copy/mimic/translate.

Comment: *"How will it behave if i put power app inside Xamarin Forms WebView?"* - AFAIK, for that to work, the Power App is hosted on some server, and you enter the URL of the Power App page to show. It won't even be aware it is inside an XF app; its like running any web site in any browser.

Comment: Here's another clue re "just don't go down this road": Until you wrote this question, there were ZERO StackOverflow questions that had BOTH of these tags together. `[xamarin.forms] [powerapps]`. If there is one thing I've learned in years of programming different technologies, the more people trying to do what you are doing, the greater chance of success. No one has even come here before to ASK whether this could be done. Personally, that would tell me all I need to know. Also, google this `"xamarin forms" "powerapps"`. IMPORTANT: Include those quotes. That tells google both must be on a page.

Comment: even with just [xamarin] [powerapps] there is still just this one post